# Apache Camel question on routing via javaDSL

Tags: apache-camel

When using routing in a Camel context via RouteBuilder, What is the practical difference between:

1) from(A).to(B).to(C);

2) from(A).to(B); from(B).to(C)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) uses a single consumer from A then sends to B and sends the result of invoking B (if B returns some output) to C. So its a pipeline.

2) uses a consumer on B to send to C and won't send the output of B to C